# How to get modified date in UTC

Tags: winapi, filesystems

`GetFileAttributesEx` returns the date that the filesystem returns, unmodified. NTFS stores dates in UTC, and FAT stores them in the local time zone. Without knowing the time zone, a date is pretty worthless.

**What is the best way to reliably get the last modified date of a file in UTC?** Is the best way really to just check for NTFS vs. FAT? What if you are using a different filesystem? Is there a different API I can use? Is there some elegant code someone can post here?

Comment: That function might return the "unmodified" timestamp, but it will still need to convert from FAT time format to FILETIME format. It probably internally calls [`DosDateTimeToFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724247%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) but the the documentation for that function seems unenlightening.

Comment: Great question - I'm in the same situation, and tbh I'm hoping for someone to just paste a function that can do it, to avoid having to research in order to fill in where MSDN docs are hazy. For example they give an example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724926(VS.85).aspx which seems to assume that file times are always returned in UTC...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Win32 API [GetFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it returns all its times in UTC. Yes, FAT file system does store these values in local time, but the Win32 API is doing the UTC conversion for you.

Quote from the '[FileTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)' MSDN documentation:

> GetFileTime retrieves cached UTC times from the FAT file system.

Answer (score 2):

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

*The FAT file system records times on disk in local time. GetFileTime retrieves cached UTC times from the FAT file system. When it becomes daylight saving time, the time retrieved by GetFileTime is off an hour, because the cache is not updated. When you restart the computer, the cached time that GetFileTime retrieves is correct. FindFirstFile retrieves the local time from the FAT file system and converts it to UTC by using the current settings for the time zone and daylight saving time. Therefore, if it is daylight saving time, FindFirstFile takes daylight saving time into account, even if the file time you are converting is in standard time.*